# How to put 65 .json files in one table

Tags: json, r

I'm using `streamR` to read tweets as .json files. I want to put all `json` files into a table. How can I do this in R and use it for analysis?

```
tweets.df <- parseTweets("xxx.json",simplify=TRUE )
```

Answer (score 1):

So if `myfiles` is the list of your json files, then

```
df<-do.call(rbind, lapply(myfiles, function(x) 
    parseTweets(x",simplify=TRUE)
))
```

Should read them, convert them to a `data.frame` then stack all the `data.frames`.

Comment: Or, slightly simpler: `do.call(rbind, lapply(myfiles, parseTweets, simplify = TRUE))`.